# Other modules not visible from module

Tags: julia

I am currently learning Julia (1 week, finished the first 15 sections in https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JuliaLang/docs.julialang.org/assets/julia-1.6.1.pdf).

Currently don't understand how module in Julia works.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
module ModuleA
    foo = 3
end

module ModuleB
    bar = ModuleA.foo
end

println(ModuleB.bar)
```

How does it give the error `ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: ModuleA not defined` at line `bar = ModuleA.foo`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ModuleA got defined within the module `Main` so in your case it needs to be:

```
bar = Main.ModuleA.foo
```

Or you can import `ModuleA` as:

```
module ModuleB
    using Main.ModuleA
    bar = ModuleA.foo
end
```

Comment: Also `using ..ModuleA` works (or `import ..ModuleA`).

Comment: yes! in this case the first dot is an alias for `Main`